# Save Record built-in macro with custom confirmation dialog

Tags: ms-access, macros, ms-access-2010

I was wondering if anyone knew how to create a custom message for the save record confirmation, only using macros and not user coded VBA. I've done this for a previous project in VBA but this time I'm trying to only use Access' macro builder. I'm using Access 2010 to build this project.

So far I've got

```
IF 6=MsgBox("Are you sure you want to delete this customer's information? WARNING, this is unrecoverable."),52 Then
RunMenuCommand DeleteRecord
MessageBox Message "Customer information deleted."
```

This makes a yes no dialog box first as the confirmation but it then shows the built-in confirmation that Access bundles with the DeleteRecord command.

Thanks,
Jake.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

don't use the run menu command. You could for example delete using SQL

```
currentdb.execute "DELETE * FROM myTable WHERE myTableId=" & idOfRecordToBeDeleted
```

Answer (score 0):

Looking for a similar solution myself and after much ado, have a solution. Using Access2013, but should be the same logic.

In my case, I wanted a Yes/No message box to add a record on Yes, and reload the form on No. In your case, leaving out the filters and values, it would be simpler... If yes, RunMenuCommand = Delete Record Else StopMacro. You could set up the specifics for No, but Else handles it for me.

Specifics: I have a form with a combo box (macro is tied to the combo box/After Update property) to select and filter the records. If there is a matching record(s), display it(them). If there is no matching record, display a message (no records) and prompt the user to add one (yes) or not (no).

The entire macro.... (no VB)

`ApplyFilter
   Filter Name (blank)
   Where Condition =="[cID]= "& Str(Nz([Screen].[ActiveControl],0))
   Control Name (blank)`

`If IsNull(eID]) Then
     If MsgBox("No record",4,"Nothing found")=6 Then
        SetProperty
          Control Name cID
            Property Value
             Value =Str(Nz([Screen].[ActiveControl],0))
         StopMacro
     Else
        RunMenuCommand
            Command RemoveAllFilters
        StopMacro
      End If
End If`